# Chrome ухудшает качество svg

Tags: google-chrome, svg

В один прекрасный момент просто поколбасило svg-иконки в chrome.
[link](https://monosnap.com/file/Mkj6lPRC7CijdgUXtiHPOHD4ez0wVP)
Код не менялся. В остальных браузерах все ок

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте заюзать shape-rendering
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering

Comment: не помогло. Дело в том, что когда загрузка все страницы идет - логотип нормальный. Как только загрузка закончилась, такое чувство что оно его меняет на логотип с качеством на несколько порядков ниже

Comment: Кстати, добавил этот атрибут и в firefox все поехало. Убрал - все ок. В хроме все без изменений

Comment: попробуйте проверить SVG вне сайта. подгрузите его на чистый html. может что-то другое на сайте ломает.

Comment: проверил. дело в svg